# ifconfig -a get needed data grepping

Tags: networking, arch-linux, scripting

If I issue following command to obtain network interface data:

```
[root@pi lib]# ifconfig -a

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.154  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether b8:27:eb:3c:03:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44219  bytes 17569207 (16.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9964  bytes 7176485 (6.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 229  bytes 21989 (21.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 229  bytes 21989 (21.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:11:6b:f0:bb:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@pi lib]#
```

How do I get network interface name, it's ip, subnet mask, gateway and mac address from terminal?

Comment: Try starting with `ip address show`.  Use `ip route` to get the gateway.

Comment: If you don't mind installing `puppet`, there is a `facter` command that you can use to get these info in a reader-friendly format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using `ip a`, but with your current output, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { RS="\n\n"} 
  /eth0/ && /UP/ {ifc=$1; ip=$6; subn=$8; gway=$10; mac=$12} 
  END {print "Interface: "ifc "\nIP: "ip "\nSubnet: "subn "\nGateway: "gway "\nMac: "mac}
' <(ifconfig -a)

Interface: eth0:
IP: 192.168.0.154
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.255
Mac: b8:27:eb:3c:03:fe
```

This will only print the details of an interface if it is up.

Comment: How do I do it using ip a, it is really better way!

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Look at the output of `ip a` (it is quite similar) and match the relevant fields (eg, $1, $6 etc)...

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Because that made sense based on your question...

Comment: Gateway ouput is wrong: my gateway (router) resides at address 192.168.0.1

Comment: @Marko I'm sure you can work it out from here...

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

ip r l && ip addr show {interface name} | grep ether

Ex. ip r l && ip addr show eth0 | grep ether

Sample output

`ip r l && ip addr show wlan0 | grep ether
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.42 
    link/ether e4:d5:3d:ef:90:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

`ip r l` this will give you gateway, ip ,interface,netmask

`ip addr show {interface name}`  This will give you rest of details mac address

Comment: but I need info for ALL interfaces, including INACTIVE

Comment: just do ip r l && ip addr this will give you all info or interface serial number ex,eth0,eth1 then simply ip r l && ip addr | grep ether this will print mac addr sequentially